# Google-cloud-build cannot be canceled

Tags: google-cloud-build

This is a very specific question about one of our cloud-builds.

A certain build, that is usually running within 10 minutes, is running almost 2 hours now. It seems that it is stuck in one build step. I tried cancel the build through the website and the cli via `gcloud builds cancel` but both didnt' work.

Although gcloud is returning `Cancelled [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../builds/...]`, the build still is up and running.

Our build-timeout is set for 30 minutes but it was simply ignored.

Any idea how to cancel this build?

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/cancel

Comment: Already tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem "solved" itself after waiting long enough. After almost 2 1/2 hours the build finally canceld itself.

The same build triggered afterwards finished without any problems.